# Vue.js Firestore Fill select dynamically

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, materialized-views

I'm using Firestore to retrieve some data which I want to be populated in the select.

Here is my select:

```
     <li>
        <div class="row container">
           <div class="input-field col s12">
             <select name="organizers" id="organizersSelector" v- 
                                         model="selectedOrganizer">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose 
                                                  organizer</option>
                    <option v-for="organizer in organizers"
            v-bind:key="organizer.name" v-bind:value="organizer.name">{{organizer.name}}</option>
             </select>
             <label for="organizers">Organizers</label>
           </div>
       </div>
    </li>
```

So, I inside the data I have an empty array of `organizers`:

```
  data() {
return {
  name: null,
  organizer: null,
  originalUrl: null,
  organizers: [],
  selectedOrganizer: null,
  ...
};
```

},

Then when page is created I try to reach my Firestore collection and then `push` object into the related collection:

```
created() {
db
  .collection("collection_name")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      this.organizers.push(doc.data());
    });
    alert("size = " + this.organizers.length + " ; name = " + 
             this.organizers[0].name);
  });
 }
```

As I see from `alert` my array is populated and there're object with `name` property. Nevertheless, my `select` shows me the only default option and pressing it I can't find any `name`s.

How to populate `select` after the response from `Firestore`?

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

I use `materializedcss` to have better UI, but I can't understand why I need to refresh the page to activate prepopulated `input`s. As well I can see only the `label` for `select`, but `select` itself doesn't render. After the refresh it appears.

Following documentation I added this to 'index.html' just after linking `jQuery`

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slide-out").sidenav();
  $("#organizersSelector").formSelect();
  $("#levelsSelector").not('disabled').formSelect();
   });
 </script>
```

I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<option value="" disabled selected>Choose organizer</option>` line?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it looks like a simple label